# AngularJS filter not working with $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

My AngularJS app is supposed to show courses and their equivalences in a table. The table is supposed to dynamically show the results based on the input from a select element.

**HTML**

```
<form name = "Select University" ng-show = "courseType == 'extern'">
    <label for = "University"> University: </label>
    <select name = "University" id = "repeatSelect" ng-change = "changeIt()"ng-model = "univs.repeatSelect">
            <option ng-repeat = "univ in univs.uniNames | orderBy: 'School'" > {{univ.School}} </option>
    </select>
    </form>



 Courses at {{univs.repeatSelect}}
    <table>
            <tr>
            <th> Course </th>
            <th> Equivelance </th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: 'className' | filter:univs.repeatSelect">
            <td>{{ x.className }}</td>
            <td> {{x.equiv}} </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$http.get("http://linux.students.engr.scu.edu/~cmulloy/COEN174/getSchools.php")
    .success(function (response) 
    {
            $scope.univs.uniNames = response.records;
    });

$scope.univs = 
    {
            repeatSelect: null,
            uniNames: null,
    };
```

The scope variable `{{univs.repeatSelect}}` shows up on the page. For example, it will show "Courses at UCLA" above the table. But the table is empty when I use `univs.repeatSelect` as the filter argument for `ng-repeat`. However, if I explicitly use 'UCLA' as the filter argument, it works and shows the courses at UCLA. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `value` attribute to your select `options` which will assign that `value` attribute value to the respective `ng-model`.

```
<select name = "University" id = "repeatSelect" ng-change="changeIt()" ng-model="univs.repeatSelect">
    <option ng-repeat="univ in univs.uniNames | orderBy: 'School'" value="{{niv.School}}"> {{univ.School}} </option>
</select>
```

Better option would be use `ng-options` here while dealing with `select` box.

```
<select name="University" id="repeatSelect" 
   ng-change="changeIt()" ng-model="univs.repeatSelect" 
   ng-options="univ.School as univ.School in univs.uniNames | orderBy: 'School'">
</select>
```

Comment: @Charles Mulloy does it helped?